# microsoft cognitive services face api browser

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

Was wondering if anyone knew of an existing solution for browsing the Face API data I set listing and viewing the person-group hierarchy, persisted faces and person-faces, etc. Of course my own app persists the data that has been sent/received to the API but I'm looking to browse the server side.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean browsing the face images?  These are not available from the Face API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So got an official answer from MSFT Cognitive Services support (real quick turnaround!):

"We currently do not have a console app that provides the capabilities that you are seeking.  The current avaialble method to retrieve this lit is done through Person Group - List Person Groups and Person - List Persons in a Person Group."

Guess its code then.